# Event to find out all feature successfully loaded to the layer

Tags: openlayers-6

I am using OpenLayers6 to load the map on my website. How can I know if all the features in the geojson file completed the loading to the layer?

```
 var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: "test.geojson",
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        }),
        style: function(feature) {
            return style;
        }
    });
    map.addLayer(layer);
```

Is there any event to know that I have completed the loading of all feature inside the "test.geojson" to the layer?

Comment: Currently when multiple features are added a change event is fired after the final addfeature event https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-bash-um860?file=/main.js  There is a proposal for featuresloadstart and featuresloadend events https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/11628

Comment: featuresloadend is available now, see the docs: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector.VectorSourceEvent.html